# YourKit - What does finished Thread mean?

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling, yourkit

I am using YourKit to profile my web application.
If there is a Java thread listed on Yourkit's Threads-view and that one is also marked as finished, does it mean that the thread is finished but the thread-object is still present (not removed by garbage collection)? Or does Yourkit also display old finished threads without an existing thread object? I could not find any documentation about this topic.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are threads that have already exited their `run()` method. It doesn't matter, if the thread object still exists or is already dead and collected by the GC.

So, the Threads tab in YourKit shows the real activity of threads, not `Thread` objects lifetimes. The thread line starts when the `run()` method starts and ends when the thread exits this method.